# Incomplete CSV/Excel rows downloaded from DT buttons through RMarkdown-Shiny

Tags: r, datatables, shiny, r-markdown

I have the following **[RMarkdown Shiny](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/authoring_shiny.html)** document:

````
---
title: "Title"
runtime: shiny
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    vertical_layout: scroll
    theme:  bootstrap
    orientation: rows
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(flexdashboard)
```



Rows {data-height=400}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### Table

``` {r show_table}
library(DT)
library(ggplot2)
renderDataTable( {
  dat  <- diamonds
   },
   extensions = c('Scroller','Buttons'),
    class = 'compact cell-border stripe',  rownames = FALSE,
    filter = list( position = 'top', clear = FALSE, plain =TRUE ),
    options = list(
        deferRender = FALSE,
        scrollY = 200,
        scroller = TRUE,
        dom = 'Bfrtip',
        buttons = c('csv', 'excel')
      )
  )
```
````

Which produces this document:

[image]

After I download the Excel file, the number of rows is just ~90 lines
not complete 53,940 entries. Why is that and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2):

By default `DT` uses [Server-side Processing](https://rstudio.github.io/DT/server.html) so only the visible data are sent to the browser. That is why the Excel file only contains the visible data (if you remove `scrollY = 200` and `scroller = TRUE` this becomes very clear).

To download all data you need to disable Server-side Processing by including `server = FALSE`, e.g.

```
class = 'compact cell-border stripe',  rownames = FALSE,
server = FALSE,
filter = list( position = 'top', clear = FALSE, plain =TRUE ),
```

Unfortunately, this makes loading and browsing the table extremely slow (on my computer at least).

BTW: Your code depends on the `diamonds` dataset which is part of `ggplot2`.